# Is it possible to run the grunt command after a yeoman generator install?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator

Basically I'd like to run `grunt` after my generator finishes installing dependencies, I found that you can add a `callback` function to the `installDependencies` method to run after everything has been installed like this:

```
this.on('end', function () {
    this.installDependencies({
        skipInstall: options['skip-install'],
        callback: function () {
            console.log('All done!');
        }
    });
});
```

However I'm not sure how to run the `grunt` task (as in going to the terminal and running "grunt")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After this.on('end') add this lines

```
// Now you can bind to the dependencies installed event
this.on('dependenciesInstalled', function() {
    this.spawnCommand('grunt', ['build']);
});
```

check this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841273/how-to-run-a-grunt-task-after-my-yeoman-generator-finishes-installing/18985221#18985221) for more details.

But if you're using the latest update of yeomen, you'll need to make it like this

```
this.on('end', function () {
  if (!this.options['skip-install']) {
    this.npmInstall();
    this.spawnCommand('grunt', ['prepare']); // change 'prepare' with your task.
  }
});
```